# Is a BMS supposed to be rated at your discharge current or the battery's?

Tags: bms

So if I'm making a 13s2p 48v 16Ah battery out of these cells that are rated at 200A each, (3.7v 8Ah), and if I want to power a ~30Amp motor, do I need a 200Amp BMS or a 40amp (40 not 30 because 40 is bigger than the motor discharge current to be safe)

Comment: Motors can take several times their rated current when starting. Also, you don't want to stress the battery unnecessarily. I'd probably look for a 100-150A BMS.

Comment: I struggled with this, also.  To overcome the inertial of getting rotor started, starting current can be 5 to 8 times rated current (30A), so your 40A BMS will shutdown during starting.